# EF FluentAPI how to make navigation property accessible by either object or Id

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first

I have a POCO `User` that has a `Company` property.
When create a `User` in WebAPI I would like to just set the `Company_Id` that I am getting passed in json in the request and not have to load the `Company` entity from the database context in order to set it in the `User`.
I tried adding a `User.Company_Id` property in addition to the `User.Company` property and migrations ends up creating a `Company_Id1` column in my database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should use Forign key attribute to let EF know it's a foreign key.

```
public class User 
{ 
    [ForeignKey("Company_Id")]
    public Company Company {get;set;}
    public int Company_Id {get;set;}
}
```